# Checkout a branch on Git only if it exists on the remote server

Tags: git

As part of a continuous integration environment, I have a script that is cloning my repository and then checking out a branch of a specific name.  I would like to have this script fail if there isn't a branch with that name on the remote.  So, something like...

```
$ git clone my_repo
$ git checkout -tb foo
  FATAL: no branch foo on origin
```

Is this possible?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't it already fail? I get `error: pathspec 'foo' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: Sorry, missed a flag on that line.  See the edited code.

Comment: What happens if you remove the "b" option? You are not creating a new branch. You are trying to pull an existing one. So -b should be incorrect if I'm not misstaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just dubbel checked. Just remove the "b" option and you are good to go.

> git checkout -t foobar
>
> fatal: Missing branch name; try -b